# Java - Count Method Calls Inside A Method

Tags: java, methods, static, count

i know that this works in C/C++ but somehow I wont find a way in java to get this working.

I have about 50 methods and I want to count how many times i called them. It would work if I made 50 variables outside the method and inside I simply increment them.

But that are way to much variables. Is there a way to handle this with one variable inside the function? Or with one variable outside the methods.

I need just a way to do this with one variable.

Has anyone an Idea?

Comment: arrays to your rescue.

Comment: Use a `HashMap<String, Integer>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decalare this where its available to access from.

```
Map<String, Integer> callCount=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Then In every method do something like:

```
public void anyMethod()
{
    Integer count=callCount.get("anyMethod"); 

    if(count==null)
    {
        count= new Integer(0);
    }

    count++;
    callCount.put("anyMethod",count);

    /**
    other things that your method do......
    **/
}
```

Comment: don't have IDE now so please ignore any typo if there any.

Answer (score 1):

`Map<String,Integer> counters = new HashMap<>();`

`String` is the method name (or whatever you want it to be) and `Integer` is the counter.

Just declare it outside your functions, and increment each value in the `Map` when you are hitting your method (according to the key, which is the method name)